# Como trabalhar com mais de uma substituição em Python usando o Replace?

Tags: python

Como trabalhar com mais de uma substituição em Python usando o Replace?

Observação: Não é permitido o uso do FOR nem FUNÇÂO e sem DICIONARIO.

Exemplo:

```
print("Bolacha".replace('a', 'e').replace('o', 'u'))
```

Como melhorar o código acima sem ter que ficar repetindo .replace....?

Comment: Cria tua function que faz isso do jeito que quer !!! E porque não pode usar `FOR` ???

Comment: Não pode usar função nem for. É um desafio.

Answer (score 8):

Em `Python 3`, o tipo primitivo [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#text-sequence-type-str) fornece interface para isso. Você pode criar uma tabela de tradução usando o método estático [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) e, em seguida, realizar a operação de substituição usando o método [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate):

```
entrada = "Bolacha"

tabela = str.maketrans( 'ao', 'eu' )     

saida = entrada.translate( tabela )

print(saida)
```

Ou:

```
print("Bolacha".translate( str.maketrans( 'ao', 'eu' )))
```

Saída:

```
Buleche
```